# How to add a file to the index in a git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I've looked around for duplicates and while some of them have similar titles, I haven't found anyone having the same issue as I am, so here goes.

I've written a script that runs on `pre-commit` and uses the output of `git status --porcelain` to compile any LESS file in my project that has changed. This part works fine. But I want the .css files to be included in the current commit. So in addition to running the compiler, my script runs `git add <filename>`. And here's where things get tricky.

The file *is* added to the index, but it's not the index of the current commit. So if I modify `style.less`, and run `git commit -a` (or manually `git add style.less`) the compiler should generate `style.css` and `style.min.css` and add them to the current commit. But the behavior I've noticed is only `style.less` is committed, despite the two `.css` files being added to the index for the next commit.

So my question is: is there a way to add files to a commit in a pre-commit hook so that they take effect for that commit? Note that before the pre-commit hook is run, those two `.css` files aren't modified, so I can't just add them before that. I also know I can exit the hook with a non-zero status so the commit is cancelled but the files are added, but I hope to avoid that. Any better ideas?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Why do you want to do this in the first place? You are trying head to include generated files into version control, which is in general a not-so-good ideas anyway. If you need the style.min.css to be there on checkout, why can't you generate it after checkout in a build step?

Comment: Because CSS files aren't binary files, they're just static text files. Generated files aren't put in version control because they typically cause merge conflicts where you don't really have a good way to resolve them (binary files), but for CSS files you rarely have that problem. I didn't want to have to install a LESS compiler on our webservers to do it post-merge/update. However, all that said, it did prove to be an easier way to accomplish what I was trying to do, even though it wasn't ideal.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This doesnt solve the problem at all.

Comment: I guess he accepted my "your doing it wrong" non-answer, because in this case it solved his problem (arguably without answering his question). If he doesn't check the LESS files in in the first place, the "how do i slipstream them into the commit" problem goes away.

Answer (score 14):

I am unable to reproduce your problem.  My initial guess was that the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable was being unset by your `pre-commit` hook.  However, when I tried unsetting `GIT_INDEX_FILE` from `pre-commit`, I got a different problem (Git complained that `.git/index` was locked).

Here's an example script showing that Git functions as you expect and that something else must be wrong.  This script initializes a new test repository, creates a `pre-commit` hook that emulates what your hook does, and makes a few test commits:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# initialize the test repository
rm -rf testrepo
git init testrepo
cd testrepo

# create the pre-commit hook
cat <<\EOF >.git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/sh
git status --porcelain | while IFS= read -r line; do
    # todo: handle renames and deletions of a *.less file
    f=${line#???}
    case ${f} in
        *.less)
            fb=${f%.less}
            echo bar >>"${fb}".css
            echo baz >>"${fb}".min.css
            git add "${fb}".css "${fb}".min.css
            ;;
    esac
done
EOF
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

# create foo.less, commit it
echo foo >foo.less
git add foo.less
git commit -m "add foo.less"

# modify foo.less, commit it
echo foo2 >>foo.less
git commit -a -m "modify foo.less"
```

If you run `git log -p` in the test repository and look at the resulting commits, you'll see that `foo.css` and `foo.min.css` were modified whenever `foo.less` was modified.

Here's why I thought your problem was caused by changing/unsetting the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable:

When `git commit -a` is run, Git makes a temporary index file and uses that instead of the default `.git/index` to create the commit.  In order for operations like `git add` to work from within a `pre-commit` hook, Git sets the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable to the name of the temporary index it created before running `pre-commit`.  If your hook unsets `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, or sets it to `.git/index`, then all Git operations from within your hook will try to modify the original index, not the temporary index that is used to generate the commit.

However, the temporary index file also acts as a lock on the original index file.  If a hook tries to modify the original index, and the temporary index exists, then Git will abort with an error.

Comment: I ran your script and it worked as expected, contrary to how my real repository actually behaves. I'll look into this more a little later and get back to you if I figure something out. Thanks!

Comment: Gave you the bounty because of the effort, even though I still wasn't able to figure out what was going on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that you could have the git attribute 'clean' to be a script which updates the generated files.  Normally that hook can run a script to tidy up your source code but I think it could be used to "cleanup" your generated output.
This attribute is triggered when you do 'git add' and you could have the script do another 'git add' on the generated file.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? I did some Googling and found some information on Git attributes but nothing on how to attach a script to them or how an `add` attribute might be laid out.

Answer (score 0):

You may take advantage of amending the last commit. Just an idea.

Comment: I did consider this option, but I hope to avoid it. It involves running a commit, running the hook, then letting the original commit finish and then running a second commit (unless I'm missing something), which seems complicated to do manually, and sort of ridiculous to do automatically using hooks.

Comment: Though when automatically run by the hook, it will do the job flawlessly.